# Continuity of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2/n}}{n(n!)^2}, 0\leq x\leq 1$

Tags: analysis

I'm reading J. Marsden - Elementary Classical Analysis 2nd ed. p.244 #5.

My sketch was first defining
$$f_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{x^{2/n}}{n(n!)^2}$$
and show that for every $\epsilon>0$, $N>0$ exists s.t.
$$k\geq N \implies \forall x\in[0,1],\; |f(x)-f_k(x)|=|\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{2/n}}{n(n!)^2}|\leq|\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!}|<\epsilon$$

I know that the last inequality should be true, but cannot write analytically.

Can anyone suggest the proof?

Comment: The last term is just the residue of the absolutely convergent series $e^1=\sum 1/n!$.

Comment: @Vim I understand that, but still can't write precisely..

Comment: what's the definition of convergence?

Comment: @Vim for all $\epsilon >0$, $N>0$ exists s.t. $k\geq N \implies |X_k - X|<\epsilon$, but this time $X$ will be zero and then nothing changes.

Comment: no. This time $X=e$ and $X_k=\sum_{i=1}^k 1/i!$.

Comment: @Vim OH..very thank you!